# Cavalieri’s Principle for calculating volume.

Tags: functions, volume

Let $B = \{(x, y, z): x^2 +y^2 +z^2 ≤ 4\}$ be the ball with radius $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let
$V$ be the region inside $B$ above the plane $z = 1$. Use Cavalieri’s Principle
to compute the volume of $V$.

I understand how to use Cavalieri’s Principle as you simply find the area of the cross section and then integrate that between the height. However, I don't understand how to do it for only part of the sphere. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region above the plane $z=1$ has height between $1$ and $2$ (the radius of the sphere). Thus, you only need to integrate

$$ I= \int_1^2 Area(x^2+y^2 \leq 4-h^2)dh $$
Note that the region $x^2+y^2 \leq 4-h^2$ is a circle of radius $\sqrt{4-h^2}$. Therefore the integral becomes
$$ I = \int_1^2 \pi(4-h^2)dh$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Did you just replace the z with h or is h the height?

Comment: Yes, I did replace $z$ with height, since they mean the same thing (if you orient your $z$ axis up)